# How to detect when pressing down on UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I want to implement a scale animation when the user presses down on a **UITabBarItem**. How can I detect when a tabBarItem in a tabBar is being pressed down?

My thinking so far is that perhaps there is a method in the `UITabBarControllerDelegate`?

I haven't seen a SO question on this...

Thanks, this issue has been holding me back hours!

Comment: APOLOGIES!, I **meant UITabBarItem not UIBarButtonItem**

Comment: For a tab bar, I think you need to create your own version of `UITabBar` and `UITabBarController` :(...

Comment: @Sweeper yes, unfortunately that is the case

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The general idea is, you need to create your own custom `UIView`, and then pass that into [this initialiser](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/1617151-init).

```
let customView = MyCustomBarButtonItem()
let barButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: customView)
```

As for how you implement the custom view so that you can detect touch downs, you have many choices.

You can either use `touchesBegan` to detect the touch down, and `touchesEnded` to detect a "tap" on the bar button item.

```
class MyCustomBarButtonItem: UIView {
    // ...

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        // ...
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Another way is to subclass `UIButton`, and add target/action pairs for the `.touchDown`/`.touchUpInside` control events.

Comment: Also you can subclass `UIControl` (or `UIButton`, it doesn't matter) and add `didSet` observer to `isHighlighted`. It is `true` when pressed and `false` otherwise. In addition it handles touching down and moving out out of the box

Answer (score 0):

These are the delegate methods which get called when a user selects a `tabBarItem`:

```
// UITabBarDelegate
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    print("Selected item")
}

// UITabBarControllerDelegate
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
    print("Selected view controller")
}
```

Comment: well yes, but this is only _after_ selecting (i.e. after the user lets go..), however I need to animate upon the press down... :)